# What is this address and for what?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, etherscan

What is this address and for what?
0x000000000000000000000000000000000000bEEF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely a public address with no known private key, which can be used by convention for a set of actions available only to the contract owner (since no one has the private key of this address).

For example, the owner of an ERC20 token contract can implement a pair of `onlyOwner` functions for minting tokens at this address, and for transferring them from this address to some other address (an address whose owner DOES have the private key of).